# Send HTML form data to external javascript and send post request from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post, forms, http-post

I am trying to build a webpage where user enters phone number and that phone number is sent to server through HTML POST request, like this:

```
<form action="/collectUserData" method="POST">
  <div>
    <input name="to" value="Enter your phone number">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

However, I dont want to use this method because I also want to send the geo-coordinates of the user to the server, along with the phone number. The geo-coordinates can be captured through few lines of javascript.

So what I want is, once the user enters phone number in the input text box and press the Submit button, the form data should be sent to a js file running in the same directory. Let the name of the js file be `sendUserInfo.js`

This js file should receive the phone number of user, determine coordinates, and then push the phone numnber and latitude to the server through a post request.

The geo coordinate identification part is sorted out. Therefore, I need help regarding

1) Sending form data to a js file running in same directory (strictly not in the HTML with `script` tag, but in a separate js file)

2) Push the data from the javascript to server with a POST request.

I searched on methods to do it quite a large but could not find methods which strictly do not use inline js with `<script></script>` tags whereas I need something with a separate js file. Any help will be appreciated.

**Answers specific to node.js are most welcome.**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onclick attribute on the submit button. In the example below I've used jquery for the ajax call.

```
<form action="#" >
  <div>
    <input id="to" name="to" value="Enter your phone number">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="sendInfo(event)">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sendUserInfo.js"></script>
```

sendUserInfo.js

```
function sendInfo(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        ele = document.getElementById("to");

        $.ajax({

            url: "/collectUserData",
            data: {
                phone_number: ele.value,
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                long: position.coords.longitude
            },
            method: "POST",
            success: function(){
                //handle successful post
            },
            error: function(){
                //handle error
            }


        })
    }, function(){

        //handle error

    })

}
```

Comment: Because this line '<script src="sendUserInfo.js"></script>' is written outside the '<form></form>' tag, how will browser identify that this script has to be called from this particular submit button?

Further, how will browser identify that 'sendInfo(e)' function is inside this script only?

Comment: The thing is, data is not being passed to the js code and request is not going through the server from the js file.